# How to edit PayPal payment page header and footer texts

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am working on an old website which uses PayPal as one of the gateway. I need to editing header and footer texts (image embedded below) on PayPal website. I searched a lot on PayPal dashboard but can't find way to get into these settings.

I've all the credentials of this PayPal account, any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Login to your PayPal account.
- Under My Account, click Profile.
- In the My Selling Tools section (left side), click on Update next to Custom
  payment pages.
- Click the Add button. Choose a unique name for the
  payment pages style.
- Specify the URL for the logo image. Make sure it
  is on a secure server. It’s optional but shouldn’t be. Specify the
  secure URL for the header image. Input all of the colors that you
  want to change. You can then Preview how it looks, then Save when
  complete.

This way you can add your customized header image instead of displaying 
"Arvind kumar Test Store"

The header that is displayed is your business name. You can also update your business name [here](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-business-info)

Comment: Thanks Vimalnath, that's exactly what I wanted.